# Old style numbers in lucida incompatible with bold italics?

Tags: bold, italic, lucida

I'm using `lucimatx` to typeset things in Lucida. I've encountered a problem when I try to use old-style numbers: text that is intended to be ***bold italic*** is instead rendered as simply **bold**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[romanfamily=bright-osf]{lucimatx}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\emph{bold italics doesn't work}}

\emph{\textbf{this doesn't work either}}

\end{document}
```

Things work as expected if I remove `romanfamily=bright-osf` from the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bold italics do not work because there are no bold italics in the old-style figures version (aka `hlhj`).  You can however load the the bold italics from the lining figure version (aka `hlh`).  You have to do the `\DeclareFontShape` after `\begin{document}` because otherwise the `T1+hlhj` fontshape is not yet available as the `fd` file is only input after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[romanfamily=bright-osf]{lucimatx}
\begin{document}
\DeclareFontFamily\encodingdefault{hlh}{}%
\DeclareLucidaFontShape\encodingdefault{hlh}{b}{it}{hlhbi8t}{}%
\DeclareFontShape\encodingdefault\rmdefault{b}{it}{<->ssub * hlh/b/it}{}%

\textbf{\emph{bold italics doesn't work}}

\emph{\textbf{this doesn't work either}}

\end{document}
```

[image]